# Python: Question about the usage of max() and min() when the input numbers are two-digit

Tags: python, list, max

When the code below takes input such as

5 (the length of the next input)
1 3 5 2 4

it accurately returns the maximum number and the minimum number.

However, when the code takes input that includes two-digit numbers such as

5
12 52 1 65 8

it returns 8 as the maximum number and 1 as the minimum.

How should I modify my code to always return the correct outputs?

num = int(input())

nums = input().split()

print(max(nums),min(nums))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nums should be a list of integer and not list of string. currently it is list of string. you need to convert it to list of int.

`nums = list(map(int, input().split()))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out
First take input as string then convert them to a list of numbers Hope It helps

```
n=(input("enter the numbers: "))
a=list(map(int,n.split()))
print(max(a),min(a))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).